# What does this array definition do exactly?

Tags: javascript, ruby

Below is a piece of Ruby code I am rewriting in JavaScript. I understand that it packs the array as '8-bit unsigned (unsigned char)', and then unpacks it as '16-bit unsigned, VAX (little-endian) byte order', but my attempts to make it work in JavaScript have failed.

I was wondering if the `||=` has any impact on the values in the array?

I would also like to know how the packing and unpacking influences the values in the array? Does it only change `0x01` into `0x0100`?

```
@_tree_left ||= [
  0x01, 0x01, 0x03, 0x01, 0x05, 0x01, 0x07, 0x01, 0x0B, 0x01, 0x0D, 0x01,
  0xF9, 0x00, 0xFB, 0x00, 0xFD, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01
].pack('C*').unpack('v*')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `||=` is just shorthand for:

```
@_tree_left = @_tree_left || [ ... ].pack('C*').unpack('v*')
```

The first time the statement is executed, `@_tree_left` will be nil, and so it will be assigned the value of the right hand expression. If executed a second time, then as long as `@_tree_left` has any kind of a value left, it will not be changed.

It's a bit easier to see if simplified.

```
@a             # => nil
@a = @a || 123 # => 123
@a = @a || 456 # => 123, no change this time
```

The rest of the expression is storing and retrieving a specific binary string.

It can be easily duplicated in JavaScript. It's just combining every two values in the array. So it's computing:

```
b[0] = a[0] + (a[1] << 8)
b[1] = a[2] + (a[3] << 8)
. . .
```

Answer (score 2):

`||=` is a classic Ruby idiom meaning:

```
v = v || second_expression
```

If the first expression evaluates to `false` or `nil` it means second one will be executed.